# Variables inside a _partial.scss can be redefined on the imported file?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Let's assume I have 2 partial sass files:

```
_partial1.scss  
_partial2.scss
```

both are imported into:
app.scss

If I define a variable...

```
$mainColor: red //on partial1.  
$mainColor: green //on partial2 and   
$mainColor: blue //on app.scss
```

If I've set on the _partial2.scss file

```
body {
   background: $mainColor;
}
```

The color of my html background will be *green*...
BUT **I need to be able to redefine it later on my app.scss so...
Is there a way?**

I'm asking this because I'm using foundation and I have a subproject where I need to be able to change fonts and colors without changing the _settings.scss.
You can find my [original question on Zurb's Foundation forum](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/24822-redefining-variables-outside-_settingsscss) but I think an answer here could also be useful for someone else, not necessarily using foundation.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the variable at any point. Example:

**app.scss**

```
$mainColor: blue;

#container {
  background: $mainColor; //blue
}

$mainColor: red;

#alert {
  background: $mainColor; //red
}
```

And here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/2qzrdn05/).

Comment: I know that. My question is regarding the scope of the variables on partial imports.

Comment: Not sure what you mean then. Can you explain it another way?

Comment: I think the example on the question explains it quite well... I need to override a variable declared on a **imported** partial file.   If we follow the example you made... Imagine that `_bluePartial.scss` contains the variable plus it's `#container` style and is imported into the final `app.scss` file. How can I make the `#container` red without copying copy pasting the style. Only by overriding the variable `$mainColor: red;` ?

Comment: As long as you override `$mainColor` before you define the styles for `#container` everything will work fine. But you can't define the styles for `#container` with `background: $mainColor;`, and then redefine `$mainColor` later to change the color of `#container`. After all, the `.scss` file is compiled into plain `.css`.

Comment: In order to override the `background` style for `#container` defined in `_bluePartial.scss` you would need to redefine the `background` property for `#container` in `app.scss` unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah I thought somehow it could be possible... :( ... What I'm trying to do is to have many versions (colors and font wise) of Zurb's Foundation under a single installation but it turns out it's not as easy as I thought. Thanks for the help Brett!